# Select top 25% of the rows from a table having unknown number of rows in it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Assume that, I've a table with unknown number of rows in it. I wanted to extract the first 25% of the records from it.

Ex: if my table has 100 rows, I should get top 25 rows in the result.

Tried the below code:
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT FROM ; 
Seems this won't work in MySQL. Seeking for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` offers one solution:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 1.0 * rn / cnt <= 0.25;
```